# Sending parameters to java constructor vs methods

Tags: java, methods, parameters, class-constructors

I am trying to understand a better approach among below 2 approaches in java

Approach 1:

```
Class C1 {
    private final Properties props;
    C1(Properties p) {
        props = p;
    }

    public String method1() {
        //return some string using props
    }

    public void method2() {
       //do something using props
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
Class C1 {
   //Default Constructor

    public String method1(Properties props) {
        //return some string using props
    }

    public void method2(Properties props) {
       //do something using props
    }
}
```

I am curious to know which approach is better than other and why, if

1. I plan to instantiate this class only once.
2. I have to instantiate this class multiple times

Comment: that depends on the circumstances. can the value of props be different for both methods?

Comment: It depends, if the properties is the same always - first approach, else second approach

Comment: IS C1 really a dependency of C1? Can C1 exist without properties? if not then constructor is better way else method injection.

Comment: There is not better approach here but different approaches that suit better according to your requirement and your overall design. Please specify a context if you want to useful answer.

Comment: What do the methods do? You will need to explain further as it depends ...

Comment: @Stultuske and user7294900 the value of props is going to be same for both the methods

Comment: @SMA -  Sorry, I didnt get your question - "IS C1 really a dependency of C1?". My question is if the methods in C1 are dependent on same props, so is it better to send props to each method or just send once to constructor while instantiating.

Comment: @VikashTalanki it might, but according to your implementation, they might be different. Also, if you go for option 1, between two instances the values might be different

Answer (score 0):

---

When you use the Approach1 you don't have to think about properties when you will use the class's methods.